# Duplicate entry ' ' for key '...PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using mysql workbench 8.0 CE. 
The table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Table`.`staff` (
  `StaffNumber` INT NOT NULL,
  `NameFirst` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `NameLast` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `AdressStreet` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `PostalArea` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `PostalCode` INT NULL,
  `tlf` INT NULL,
  `Birth` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `sex` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `SSN` INT NULL,
  `position` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Salary` FLOAT NULL,
  `Veterinary_Clinics_Clinicnumber` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StaffNumber`),
  INDEX `fk_Staff_Veterinary_Clinics_idx` (`Veterinary_Clinics_Clinicnumber` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Staff_Veterinary_Clinics`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Veterinary_Clinics_Clinicnumber`)
    REFERENCES `Table`.`Veterinary_Clinics` (`Clinicnumber`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;`
```

And it contains this:

```
insert into `Table`.`staff`(
  `StaffNumber`, 
  `NameFirst`, 
  `NameLast`,
  `AdressStreet`,
  `PostalArea`,
  `PostalCode`,
  `tlf`,
  `Birth`,
  `sex`,
  `SSN`,
  `position`,
  `Salary`,
  `Veterinary_Clinics_Clinicnumber`
) 
values 
( 12, 'Name', 'LastName', 'Street', 'Place', 4217, 41354607, 
  '22.05.1976', 'Woman', 2, 'Doctor', 5000.00, 1 
);
```

When I execute this, I get the error "Duplicate entry '12' for 'staff.PRIMARY'". I do not have two of the same values in the same column, and the values matches, so I cant see where the problem is... can someone help me out.

Comment: The error is clear can you prove that it's not a duplicate?

Comment: it looks like you already have an entry with staffnumber=12 in your staff table

Comment: I changed the number to 3 and didn't get the error anymore, but i do not understand why it doesn't work with 12... I then added another column and now I get the error "Column count doesn't match value count 1" but the statement is not bigger or smaller than the number of columns the table has...

Comment: Perform `SELECT StaffNumber FROM Staff` - you will see all values which are already present in a table and so cannot be used.

Comment: There is no problem with 12 as a staffnumber as long as it doesn't already exist in table see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9PYKuv1KuPMpE2x8X9sz4s/0

Comment: Thank you! Still have problems with adding another column tho...

Comment: Figured it out, kind of.. I am just executing one line at a time, takes time but works.